# casting interface to upperclass in java

Tags: java, interface, casting

so I define a interface

```
public interface Behavior {
public void eat();

public void sleep();}
```

and i define a class like this

```
class Son extends Father implements Behavior {

@Override
public void eat() {
    System.out.println("eat");
}

@Override
public void sleep() {
    System.out.println("sleep");
}
}
```

does it make sense that after create a variable `Father father = new Son()`,

using the casting like (Behavior)father, if it does, how does it work?,will it invoke the method from object `Son`?

Answer (score 0):

Due to dynamic method binding/polymorphysm, at runtime JVM will always go for object type instead of reference type. So it will still call method of object `Son`.

Answer (score 0):

Visualize casting an object as putting new clothes on that object. It has a different appearance but underneath whatever clothes you put on it, it's still the same object.

Following snippet will clear your doubts

```
   class Father
{
    public void getFather()
    {
        System.out.println("inside father ");
    }
}

interface Behavior {
    public void eat();

    public void sleep();

}
class Son extends Father implements Behavior 
{

    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Son Eat");

    }

    public void sleep() {
        System.out.println("Son slepp");

    }

    public void getSon()
    {
        System.out.println("in son class");
    }

}

public class A 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Father f=new Son();
        f.getClass() ; //only method available 
        Behavior beh=(Behavior)f;
        beh.sleep();// methods declared in Behavior interface
        beh.eat();// methods declared in Behavior interface
        Son s =(Son)f;
        s.getSon();//methods declared in Behavior as well as methods defined in Son are available
    }
}
```

See also :
[What class does the target object take on after casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620227/what-class-does-the-target-object-take-on-after-casting?rq=1)

specially Bill K answer